# Microsoft Access: connecting to SQL Server via Active Directory username and password Trusted_Connection=no

Tags: sql-server, vba, connection-string

I have a Microsoft Access Application which generates a connection string like:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=servername;Database=db_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

This works without any problem.

What I want to do is to connect to a SQL Server instance where the user must insert his Active Directory name and password.

Like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=servername;Database=db_name;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

This only works for users which are created on the SQL Server directly.

I tried `Uid=DOMAIN\username`, but it isn't working.

Is this possible? Or is there another way how I can get through this?

The environment:
The User is using a local PC with a local account and then he's doing a "NetworkConnect" with his AD-User and password.

After that, "RunAs" as his AD-User is working BUT there is another Application that is started from the Access Application and this App must be started with the local User-Account.

SQL-Server and the AD-User are member of the same domain.

Comment: Why is the user a *local* user when he/she needs to login with the domain credentials? Why not log in with the domain credentials from the start? Are you sure *you* want to secure authentication and password security and get into trouble if the password leaks?

Comment: Because the computer isn't connected permanently via VPN-Tunnel to the company. And if you have a new user he cannot login to the computer with his AD-User because there is no profile on this computer. Therefore you need to login locally and then via NetworkConnect to the domain with your AD-User and password.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are

1. Login to SQL Server using your the Windows Domain account that you are currently logged into.  You do this automatically by specifying `Trusted_Connection=yes;`, or
2. Login to SQL Server using a SQL Login.

Those are the only two choices possible using a SQL provider connection string.  Specifically, you *cannot* use the SQL access provider to do impersonation, that is, to login to SQL Server using a *different* Windows domain account than the one that you are currently logged into.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft designed the AD integration with SQL Server to use the account of the client application, not to be able to handle logging in as a part of the connection string.  If the user isn't going to be logged into the machine using the account needed for the database access, the next best option may be something like [ShellRunAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/shellrunas) in order to let the user run your client app as the correct AD account.